# While using AutoML from EvalML getting error AttributeError: 'DataTable' object has no attribute 'to_series'

Tags: python, python-3.x, automl, evalml

I am running eval.automl on a data, made a class column as below:

```
df.loc[(df.quality<6), 'flag_class'] = 1
df.loc[(df.quality==6), 'flag_class'] = 2
df.loc[(df.quality>6), 'flag_class'] = 3
```

then splitting it as below:

X = df[['several columns inside']].copy()
y = df[['flag_class']].copy()

but when running below code getting error:

X_train, X_holdout, y_train, y_holdout = evalml.preprocessing.split_data(X, y, problem_type = 'multiclass')

error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-dffcb1214932> in <module>
----> 1 X_train, X_holdout, y_train, y_holdout = evalml.preprocessing.split_data(X, y, problem_type = 'multiclass')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\evalml\preprocessing\utils.py in split_data(X, y, 
problem_type, problem_configuration, test_size, random_seed)
     75         data_splitter = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=test_size, random_state=random_seed)
     76 
---> 77     train, test = next(data_splitter.split(X.to_dataframe(), y.to_series()))
     78 
     79     X_train = X.iloc[train]

AttributeError: 'DataTable' object has no attribute 'to_series'
```

Any support will be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you need to use their own data frame format instead of pandas data frame? You can also try MLJAR AutoML https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised - it works with multiclass classification and has an advanced feature enbineering

Comment: I had similar problem, and I noticed that I've dropped the dependence table (y), and so basically the `y` was wrong. So check if both tables are correctly separated

Answer (score 0):

DataTable is a class from the [woodwork](https://woodwork.alteryx.com/en/stable/) framework. The framework is build on top of pandas Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66P4V.png)dumie =y
type(dumie)
y_train=dumie.squeeze()
type(y_train)

Explanation: For dependent feature(y) should be series format DataTable can't convert it so First convert Y in to series by using squeeze
X should be in DataFrame format and Y should be series format

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31055564)